Multiply an input by 5 raised to the number of digits of each numbers, but my code needs reworking
I'm trying to multiply an input * 5 raised to the power of the input.
I tried this:
def multiply(n):
return 5 ** len(str(n)) * n

I tried (n = -2), but instead of giving me -10, which is the correct answer, it gave me -50
Why doesn't this output the correct numbers when n is negative?

Why are you using len(str(n)) as the power?  That makes no sense.  Negative numbers will be one character longer, because of the minus sign.

Sorry, I'm a noob, so I just used what I already knew to write this. It also works for if (n = 0)

Also, it works for if n = positive numbers, so if (n = 10), then the output is 250, and that's correct.

You're not "raising to the power of the input", you're raising to the power of the length of the input.  So an input of 2 will raise to the power 1 because the string "1" has one character, but an input of -2 will raise to the power 2 because the string "-2" has two characters.

I think maybe you want to use the absolute value, so len(str(abs(n)))?  But it's hard to say for sure, because your description of what you want is vague.

That worked! The original question runs like this: you have to multiply each number by 5 raised to the number of digits of each numbers

Can you move this to an answer?

This question probably doesn't need a formal answer, because basically it was just your misunderstanding of how len() works on a string of a negative number.  Misunderstandings and typos generally don't warrant formal answers.

I was just suggesting it so that I could mark it as useful. Thanks anyway for this.

I sort of want to suggest  int( log10( abs( n ) ) )+1 as 'power'.  I suppose n=0 might be a problem.

you are directly checking the length of your input by casting it to string:
>>> n = -2
>>> str(n)
'-2' # String with length of two -> '-' and '2' (string 2)
>>> len(str(n))
2

Maybe you can try this (not sure if it's good or bad, but will work as you expected):
# The dirty way.. 

def multiply(num: int):
    # Initialize a variable to keep track of length
    length = 0
    
    # Convert the input to string and iterate over it
    for n in str(num):

        # If the current character is int, increment the length variable
        try:
            if isinstance(int(n), int):
                length += 1

        # Above code will raise error for '-', catch here
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return 5 ** length * num

# Try with the input -2 again
print(multiply(-2))



def multiply(n):
return 5 ** len(str(abs(n))) * n    I tried this instead, and it worked. Thanks anyway for the help, will keep this in mind for future problems.

hmm.. forgot about the abs(). that's (abs()) more straight forward way. >.< sorry.

Don't worry about it, I am also new to this. I have another question coming up, so if you could help me on that, it would be great!

It will be my pleasure to help. ^^

Thank you. Also, I got the idea for using abs() from another person, so I'm still learning a lot!

-2 has a length of 2 when converted to a string, as it counts the negative sign. Thus, it's calculating 5 ** 2 * -2 = -50.
You want to ignore the negative sign when counting the digits. You could try len(str(abs(n))), which will ignore the negative sign and give you the correct answer.

-2, when converted to a string using str, becomes "-2". This is a string of length 2, because the negative sign is included within the string. You want to count the digits without the negative sign so that -2 has a length of 1

str(abs(n)) gets rid of the minus sign before converting to string.  You could also get rid of it after conversion with str(n).strip('-') and get the same answer.
